# Adding Primefaces Schedule and Schedule events dynamically on ajax update

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, bootsfaces

I have a commandbutton that takes in the required data in a form and then creates a DefaultScheduleModel along with any DefaultScheduleEvents. The commandbutton should then update another form containing TabView by dynamically creating a new tab and a new schedule along with any events that need to be created.

The problem is that for some odd reason the new tabs along with the respective schedules/events are not being created upon ajax update. The only thing I get is one tab with an empty schedule, where any subsequent submissions are do not create any additional tabs/schedules/events.

Here is my view:

```
<h:form>

        <b:panel id="createSchedule" title="Create Schedule-o-matic" >

                <f:facet name="append">
                    <b:commandButton look="danger" value="Delete" ajax="true" actionListener="#{onCallJSFBean.deleteTeamMember(teamMember)}" iconAwesome="times" icon-align="right"
                             update="rosterTable"/>
                </f:facet>
                </b:inputText>
            </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <b:commandButton value="Add Team Member" ajax="true" update="createSchedule" actionListener="#{onCallJSFBean.addTeamMember}"/>
            <f:facet name="footer">
            <b:buttonToolbar>
                <b:buttonGroup>
                <b:commandButton id='scheduleCancel' look="danger" ajax="true" value="Close" icon-awesome="window-close" update="createSchedule" 
                         onclick="ajax:onCallJSFBean.cancelSchedule();"
                         oncomplete="$('#j_id_12\\:createSchedule').hide();"/>
                <b:commandButton id='scheduleCreate' look="success" ajax="true" value="Submit" icon-awesome="fa-check"
                         actionListener="#{onCallJSFBean.createSchedule()}" update="@(.scheduleClass)"
                         />
                </b:buttonGroup>
            </b:buttonToolbar>
            </f:facet>

        </b:panel>

            </h:form>
<h:form class="scheduleClass">
            <b:row>
            <p:tabView dynamic="true" value="#{onCallJSFBean.scheduleDOs}" var="scheduleList" scrollable="true">
                <p:tab title="#{scheduleList.scheduleTitle}">
                <h:outputText value="#{scheduleList.startTime} #{scheduleList.endTime} #{scheduleList.scheduleModel.eventCount}"/>

                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            </b:row>
        </h:form>
```

And here is the respective controller:

```
//When canceling/closing the schedule creation panel     
public void cancelSchedule(){
        this.createScheduleTitle="";
        this.createScheduleCycleTime = null;
        this.slotStartTimePeriod = null;
        this.slotEndTimePeriod = null;
        this.createScheduleRoster = new ArrayList<>();
        System.err.println(scheduleDOs.size());
}

        public void createSchedule(){


        if(submitFail == true){
            this.scheduleDOs.add(createScheduleData());
            System.err.println(this.scheduleDOs.size()+" Size of tab");
        }

        System.err.println("Finished");
        }

        private ScheduleDO createScheduleData(){
        ScheduleModel scheduleModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

        if(createScheduleCycleTime == 1){
            populateDailySchedule(scheduleModel);
        }

        ScheduleDO onCall = new ScheduleDO(createScheduleTitle, createScheduleCycleTime, 
            slotStartTimePeriod, slotEndTimePeriod, createScheduleRoster, scheduleModel);

        return onCall;
        }

        private int rosterCounter = 0;
        private String nextTeamMember(List<SimpleStringWrapper> roster){
        String tmp;
        if(rosterCounter >= roster.size()){
            rosterCounter=0;
            tmp = roster.get(rosterCounter).getValue();
        }else{
            tmp = roster.get(rosterCounter).getValue();
        }
        rosterCounter+=1;
        return tmp;
        }

        private void populateDailySchedule(ScheduleModel scheduleModel){
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
        Period period = Period.months(6);
        DateTime endDate = startDate.plus(period);
        Days day = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);

        int numDays = day.getDays();

        for(int i = 0;i<numDays;i++){
            MutableDateTime startTime = new MutableDateTime(startDate.plusDays(i));
            startTime.setHourOfDay(this.slotStartTimePeriod);
            MutableDateTime endTime = new MutableDateTime(startDate.plusDays(i));
            endTime.setHourOfDay(this.slotEndTimePeriod);

            String teamMember = nextTeamMember(createScheduleRoster);
    //      System.err.println(teamMember+" "+startTime.toDate()+" "+endTime.toDate());
            DefaultScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(teamMember, startTime.toDate(), endTime.toDate());
            scheduleModel.addEvent(event);
        }
        System.err.println(scheduleModel.getEventCount());
        }
```

I'm using Primefaces 6.0 along with Bootsfaces 1.1.1

Comment: I tried to copy your code snippets into my own project. Unfortunately, the bean class is incomplete, and it requires JodaDateTime. That makes it difficult for others to understand the problem and to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my error had been in the way I had been updating the tabview/schedule, instead of having two forms and the submit commandbutton targeting the second form id, instead I had the submit button update the tabview itself.

Comment: Why does combining the two forms into a single form help? Do you really need both changes?

Comment: No that I know of, I guess it could be removed.